# how to avoid circular references in a dict-like object in js

Tags: javascript, python, dictionary, circular-reference

Consider the following example in `python`,

```py
dic_1        = {'a':1, 'b':2}
dic_1['all'] = dict( dic_1 )
>>> {'a':1, 'b':2, 'all': {'a':1, 'b':2} }
```

the function `dict()` is very useful bc we do a new object, thus not using the same pointer and therefore avoiding circular references.

How to do the same in javascript (node)? The following falls into circular ref,

```js
var dic_1    = {a:1, b:2};
dic_1['all'] = dic_1;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to achieve this :

```
dic_1 = {a:1, b:2};
dic_1['all'] = { ...dic_1 }

console.log(dic_1) // Prints {"a":1,"b":2,"all":{"a":1,"b":2}}
```

Comment: thank you, it works, that's what I wanted. solution up-scored.

Comment: No problem! Please mark my answer as solution

Comment: I've checked indeed is a bad solution. It interferes with package `babel-register`, and therefore with many intermediate apps, throwing an Unexpected token error. We need a stronger solution.